# move command with regular expressions

Tags: bash, shell

Bash is not recognizing the regular expression in this `mv` command:

```
mv ../downloads'^[exam].*$[.pdf]  ../physics2400/exams
```

I'm trying to move files from a download directory to what ever directory I have made for them to go into.

An example of such a file is `'Exam 2 Practice Homework (Solutions).pdf'`
(the single quotes are part of the file in Bash apparently.

There are many other files in the download folder hence the regex or the attempt anyway.

Comment: The shell doesn't use regular expressions for filename matching, it uses wildcard (or "glob") expressions. And your regex doesn't make sense, so I'm not sure what the glob equivalent would be.

Comment: That regex isn't going to match anything since there is text after `$`. Like @GordonDavisson says, it makes no sense. Just `mv exam.*pdf` (which is the closest guess I can make based on what you've written).

Comment: Another note: when doing bulk moves like this, *always* use `mv -i` or `mv -n` to keep `mv` from silently and irreversibly deleting files if there's a name conflict. And... do you have a backup? You should always have at least one backup of anything you don't want to lose.

Comment: @-Gordon Davisson - what does the -n option for the move command do.  I'm having trouble looking it up. its not on the man page and not showing itself in a google search.  I did find the -i option which is the interactive prompt.

Comment: @teaNcode `-n` tells `mv` not to overwrite existing files at all; it's like using `mv -i` and then entering "n" every time it asks if it should overwrite something. It's possible you have a version of `mv` that doesn't have this option (what OS & version are you using?). Here's the [Linux man page for `mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv), which lists `-n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing filename expansion, **Bash does not use regular expressions**. Instead, a type of pattern matching referred to as globbing is used. This is discussed in the [Filename Expansion section of the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).

In regards to your example file name (`Exam 2 Practice Homework (Solutions).pdf`), here are a couple things to note:

- the single quotes are not part of the file name, but are a convenience to avoid having to escape special characters in the filename (i.e. the spaces and the parentheses). Without the quotes, the filename would be specified `Exam\ 2\ Practice\ Homework\ \(Solutions\).pdf`. See the [Quoting section of the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) for further details.
- filesystems in Unix-like operating systems are case sensitive, so you need to account for the upper case `E` the filename starts with

Here's a pattern matching expression that would match your example filename as well as other files that start with `Exam` and end with `.pdf`.

```
mv ../downloads/Exam*.pdf ../phyiscs2400/exams
```

If you have files that start with both `Exam` and `exam`, you could account for both with the following:

```
mv ../downloads/[Ee]xam*.pdf ../phyiscs2400/exams
```

The bracketed expression is interpreted as *"matches any one of the enclosed characters"*. This allows you to account for both upper and lower case.

Before executing such `mv` commands, I would test the filename expansion by running `ls` to verify that the intended files are matched:

```
ls ../downloads/[Ee]xam*.pdf
```

Comment: the purpose of this move command is I have so may school files I have download from the school website in my downloads directory.  I run Ubuntu Linux on my personal laptop and an forcing myself to not use the GUI and use command line to relocate my downloaded files to the correct directories that I have made for each class.  So some are physics files, others are digital design files, ect.  all with different names and file extensions.

Comment: OK. If you **edit the question** and provide more details on the file names you're dealing with, I might be able to provide more specific guidance on how to specify a pattern matching expression. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok I edited the question and read the document link you posted in previous comment.  IF there needs to be improvements to my edit just let me know. Additionally thank you for coaching me on this site and the procedures that come with it.  still gaining experience  at posting questions.

Comment: @teaNcode -- using the GUI is fine, just keep an xterm (or two) open. If you have KDE as a desktop, then konsole provides one of the best tabbed xterms going. If not, you can always use `tmux` or `screen` to handle multiple sessions within a single xterm. You are going about it the right way. Soon you will wonder how you lived without an open terminal in every other OS you used. Pay the price of admission, go through the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), then learn `grep, sed & awk`. 10 hours spent now will save 1000's later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the regular expression, how about this?

```
find ./downloads -regex '.*\.pdf' -exec mv '{}' exams/ \;
```